# Jquery - Adding a function to element within Iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, iframe, element

I tried a lot of ways but non of them worked. For example that one works:

```
         $('#iframeid').ready( 
        function()
        {
        alert('Hello');
        }
    );
```

but following doesn't (alerts hello but do not focus.)

```
     $('a:link').click(
     function()
     {
        alert('Hello'); 
        var iframeRef = document.getElementById("iframeid");
        $(iframeRef).focus();
    $(iframeRef).contents().find("#smthing").focus(); 
     });
```

Help me work it out please.

Comment: you cannot access any iFrame displaying an other domain.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is access another document. Most (if not all) browsers block this, as it is a security problem. Having scripts load and read the contents of other sites is... well... evil.

Answer (score 0):

For security purposes you cannot access other domains in iframes with Javascript. There may even be issues with iframes from the same domain in some browsers.

If possible, I would avoid the use of iframes wherever possible. If you have the HTML content, you can add it inline with a `div` with `overflow:auto` to achieve the same effect.

As a side note, why do you use `document.getElementById("iframeid")`? You must know that you can do `$('#iframeid')` in jQuery, since you do that on the next line.

Answer (score 0):

The [Same origin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same%5Forigin%5Fpolicy) policy restricts access another domain loaded into an iframes properties from javascript.